# Removing eigenvalue from matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix $M\in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$. One of the eigenvalues of $M$ is $0$, and I wish to construct a matrix $N \in \mathbb{C}^{(n-1) \times (n-1)}$ which has the same eigenvalues as $M$, apart from the eigenvalue at $0$. What are some ways I can do this?

The eigenvector associated with the $0$ eigenvalue is known. The other eigenvalues and eigenvectors are not. They could be computed in principle. But I am not really looking for the solution $N = \text{diag}(\{\lambda_i\} \setminus 0)$, where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $M$.

Note also: $M$ has the property that for each element $m_{i,j}$ there exists an element $m_{k,l}$, such that $m_{i,j} = \overline{m_{k,l}}$. However, $k = j$ and $l = i$ isn't necessarily true, so the matrix is not hermitian. If it were, $N$ would be easily constructed via the eigendecomposition of $M$. It also true that if $\lambda \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$ is an eigenvalue of $M$, then so is $\overline{\lambda}$. Maybe these observations are helpful?

Any help and guidance much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume $0$ is a simple eigenvalue (if it isn't, it's not clear what you mean).
Then the null space of $M$ is one-dimensional (the span of an eigenvector for $0$), and the intersection of this with the column space $\mathcal{R}(M)$ is $0$.  $M$ is an invertible  linear transformation of $\mathcal{R}(M)$ onto itself.  Take any basis of
$\mathcal{R}(M)$, and let $N$ be the matrix of this linear transformation with respect to that basis.

Comment: Thank you, Robert! $0$ is indeed a simple eigenvalue. I will review your answer to make sure I understand exactly what you are saying and let you know if I have any questions!

Comment: Your method essentially requires finding the null eigenvector. This can be computationally expensive. Can we do any better?

Comment: @Radost The null eigenvector is known a priori!